# Xamarin c# Android Notification resume activity in background

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, push-notification

I'm making an app, that perform some action when back-grounded, and send a local notification in specific cases.

Now, I would like to just resume app when notification get clicked.

I saw three threads here in StackOverflow, and tried with flags, but no one worked.

This is what I tried:

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);
        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));
        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
            stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentTitle("Nuove Richieste")
            .SetContentText("Hai nuove richieste da visionare")
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.add)
            .SetPriority(1);

        Notification notification = builder.Build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
```

When notification get clicked, a black screen shows up, what's wrong?

Thanks

EDIT:

Problem is another, and still is about resuming activity, but the problem is different:

I've a TIMER perfmorming a database query every 10 seconds. If this timer is not killed, there is no way a new activity can be displayed (or the old one resumed). I can kill easily the timer when i create the notification, so the problem get solved.

By the way, the problem is when there is no notification but it is not the question case. I will open another question.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just cancel your activity so nothing is displyed.

Try to use:

> PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent

in your code:

> PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = 
>               stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0,
>   (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for more information.

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw another BIG problem in my app! I explain in edit.